# Replace some text with sed

Tags: sed

I have tried this to replace the resis_test by m.gds by searching the key word LAYOUT_PRIMARY.

```
sed -e 's/\(LAYOUT PRIMARY\).*\1 /m.gds/' < FILE.ex > b
```

FILE.ex

```
LAYOUT PRIMARY "resis_test"
LAYOUT SYSTEM GDSII

DRC RESULTS DATABASE "resis_test.drc.results" ASCII 
DRC MAXIMUM RESULTS 1000
DRC MAXIMUM VERTEX 199
```

Answer (score 3):

More secure

```
sed -e '/LAYOUT PRIMARY/s/resis_test/m.gds/' < FILE.ex > b
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 sed -e 's/\(LAYOUT PRIMARY\).*/\1 m.gds/'
                               ^^^
```

note the call to captured group in the replacement part, not in the source part.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with Below command and it worked fine

command1:

```
awk '/LAYOUT PRIMARY/{print gsub("resis_test","m.gds",$0)}1' filename
```

command2:

```
sed '/LAYOUT PRIMARY/s/resis_test/m\.gds/g' filename
```

output

```
LAYOUT PRIMARY "m.gds"
LAYOUT SYSTEM GDSII

DRC RESULTS DATABASE "resis_test.drc.results" ASCII 
DRC MAXIMUM RESULTS 1000
DRC MAXIMUM VERTEX 199
```

Comment: Note that (as also seen in the other two answers), there's no need to escape the period in the replacement section of the `s///`.